# Angular 2: ngModel binding for radio input of boolean type

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular 2, I'd like to bind 2 radio button input options in 1 group to a model property of boolean type, however either I'm not able to select one of the radio buttons or running into another incorrect binding issue.
I've tried the following in my html.

`*.component.html`:

```
Error: myModel.modelProperty is always: false, no matter which radio button is selected.

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="modelProperty">Model Property: </label>
        <form action="">
            <input type="radio" [ngModel]="_model.modelProperty"  (click)="_model.modelProperty=true" name="modelProperty" value=true>Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" [ngModel]="_model.modelProperty"  (click)="_model.modelProperty=false"  name="modelProperty" value=false>No
         </form>
</div> 

<div>{{_model.modelProperty}}</div>
```

`*.component.html`:

```
    Error: myModel.modelProperty is [Object object], only No radio button can be selected, if either Yes or No radio buttons is clicked.

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="modelProperty">Model Property: </label>
            <form action="">
                <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="_model.modelProperty"   name="modelProperty" ngValue=true>Yes<br>
                <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="_model.modelProperty"   name="modelProperty" ngValue=false>No
             </form>
    </div> 

    <div>{{_model.modelProperty}}</div>
```

I'm using the following

`*.component.ts` for all `*.component.html` options above:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {Model}    from './model';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/.../*.component.html'
})

export class *Component {

      _model = new Model(..., false, ...); //false is the Model property: .modelProperty

      constructor(){}

      ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To get your html value to evaluate as a boolean, use: `[value]="true"`

Answer (score 5):

In similar cases I use your first version of code with `[checked]` instead of `[ngModel]`.

This code works for me:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" [checked]="_model.modelProperty" 
        (click)="setProperty($event.target.checked)"
        name="modelProperty">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" [checked]="!_model.modelProperty" 
        (click)="setProperty(!$event.target.checked)" 
        name="modelProperty">No 
</form> 

setProperty(inChecked: boolean) { 
    this._model.modelProperty = inChecked; 
}
```

Comment: model property values are correct, depending on which radio buttons they select, however visually, the radio buttons are not consistently being selected when clicked.

Comment: This code works for me `<form action="">
              <input type="radio" [checked]="_model.modelProperty"  (click)="setProperty($event.target.checked)" name="modelProperty">Yes<br>
              <input type="radio" [checked]="!_model.modelProperty"  (click)="setProperty(!$event.target.checked)"  name="modelProperty">No
          </form>` with `setProperty(inChecked: boolean) {
    this._model.modelProperty = inChecked;
  }`

Comment: @Picci Works for me too. Sometimes it's better to have a code that works than a code which complies with the norms.

Answer (score 5):

For boolean, `[(ngModel)]` is working with `[value]`. 
`[(ngModel)]` fails to checked by default with `value`.
For eg:

```
<input type="radio" 
   id="idYes" 
   name="Preferred-group" 
   [value]="true" 
   [(ngModel)]="IsContactPreffered">
```

works fine.